# Changing a an image src file using javascript wont change picture displayed

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

essentially i have this div

```
<div id="trafficcam" style="text-align:center;display:none;">
<img id="image" src="http://131940.qld.gov.au/DMR.Controls/WebCams/DisplayImage.ashx?FilePath=Gold_Coast/GrandisSth.jpg" alt="Sorry, no traffic cam is available">
```

and I'd like to change the src of the file so that when a button is pressed the image changes. I can't really hide it and have it show a different one because this div is for the traffic cams, and i'd rather have it a bit more compact.

the button to execute it is

```
<input type=button  value="cam" onclick="selectCam()">
```

which i have tested and it works

the function it calls is:

```
      function selectCam()
{
alert(document.getElementById("image"))
             document.getElementbyId("image").src="http://i.imgur.com/zP9kTfe.jpg";

         }
```

which seems to not change anything on the page when the button is pressed

Comment: You forgot a semi colon after the alert. This will stop the js from running

Comment: What error do you see in the console?

Comment: @tymeJV No it wouldn't. Why would the semicolon there change anything?

Comment: the issue happens with or without the alert, and there is no error. The image just doesn't just change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method `getElementbyId`, it's called `getElementById`.
Check out the error console, there should be something like

```
Unhandled Error: 'document.getElementbyId' is not a function
```

Comment: More generally, JavaScript is case-sensetive.

Comment: jfc that was all it was. Thank you. Been working on this for two days ;_;

Comment: hey, i've applied your change and it worked in the button, but now it wont work in a drop down menu, any ideas?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4CGLPgpf this is the full code, I wasn't getting any run time errors. No files are local, just running it in coda.

Comment: Had it worked before? I think it's better to use a `select`'s `onchange` event rather than `option`'s `onclick`.

Comment: @RickyCharles Yeah, the `click` event for an `<option>` isn't supported in browsers consistently. You should only need to use the `click` event of the `<select>`

Answer (score 0):

Also watch out for the insidious `getElementByID` (the "D" shouldn't be capitalised).